# Customizing the overlay theme

Tags: theming

I am using a zen subtheme and my footer and site logo are displaying in the admin overlay. I would like to remove them.

I tried hiding them by doing the following in my theme css:

```
#overlay logo img {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#overlay #footer-wrapper {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The logo and footer are still displaying... but the styles are not being picked up...

Also, selecting or unselecting the "Use the administration theme when editing or creating content" settings makes no difference to the appearence.

[image]

Comment: paste screen shot here

Comment: I've now added a screenshot @monymirza

Comment: under "Appearance" Select "Seven" theme for "Use the administration theme"

Comment: you are using zen subtheme as admin theme? if so, read comment above.

Comment: Disable the overlay module ;)